# Windows 8.1 System Image Backup -- Unable to backup to network share due to unsupported "version of the file format"

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, nas

I have a Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit system that I am trying to make a system image backup via Windows 8.1's [System Image Backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-happened-to-backup-restore) feature. The backup destination is a network share, but the image creation is failing with the following error:

```
The version does not support this version of the file format
```

After some investigation, it appears this is due to the network share (a [Seagate BlackArmor NAS 220](http://www.seagate.com/external-hard-drives/network-storage/business/blackarmor-nas-220/)) [not supporting sparse files](https://serverfault.com/questions/433595/windows-server-backup-2012-error-the-version-does-not-support-this-version-of). The consensus out on the web seems to be that your smb.conf file on the NAS needs to have `strict allocate = yes` added, in order to support sparse files. However, as far as I can tell with the BlackArmor NAS 220, there is no way to edit the smb.conf file (and I'm not even 100% positive they're running Samba--but I bet they are).

Some more searching revealed another possible option [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/13bb79e9-c970-4805-88cb-2000b3348070/backup-failed-with-the-version-does-not-support-this-version-of-the-file-format-0xc03a0005?forum=windowsbackup):

> If you don't need to exclude files from your backup, use the
>   "-allcritical" option in your command line. AS IN:
>
> wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\backup1\backupdrive1\ -include:c:
>   -user:administrator -password:xxxx -systemState -vssFull -allcritical -quiet
>
> This changes it to Block backup and gets rid of the error.

I'm trying to do a complete backup, so no exclusions are wanted or needed. So, i tried this, and got the exact same error (only this time it was on the command line, rather than a GUI dialog).

Is there any way to do backups to a network share that doesn't support sparse files via Windows 8.1's System Image Backup facility?

Alternatively, is there a way to enable the `strict allocate = yes` on a BlackArmor NAS 220?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ssh access to your Seagate BlackArmor NAS 220.

Here is a link to how one person did it:
http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/07/10/1/enabling-ssh-on-the-seagate-blackarmor-nas-220

I am sure there are others.

This will require some knowledge on how to use linux.